# How can i add my own php code for the plugin in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress and I already know about themes and plugins. The website I am making sells product on tariff depending on the its attribute's value. For example Samsung galaxy S5 can have 65 GB and 120 GB storage and each storage have different tariff price and terms which will allow the customer to choose what he want.
But i can't find the plugin that i need. So i thought to create my own PHP code for the tariff and attributes which i don't know yet. So how can i get started  with editing the WordPress or is there a plugin for that?

I'm trying to make a web-page like this website in the link.

https://www.deinhandy.de/smartphones/apple/iphone-x/spacegrau_64gb

In the website above the customer can choose the storage he wants and the website will load the tariff for that storage.

I tried to find some pricing plan plugins but those plugins does not make my webpage to like the given link.

https://www.deinhandy.de/smartphones/apple/iphone-x/spacegrau_64gb

I need a plugin or code that makes my website looks like this.
https://www.deinhandy.de/smartphones/apple/iphone-x/spacegrau_64gb

Comment: what about woocommerce?

Comment: Are you using [WooComerce](https://woocommerce.com) plugin? It is essential for WordPress e-commerce site.

Comment: yes i am using woocommerce and i downloaded easy pricing table and dynamic pricing table for that too. but they dont look like the same as the one given in the link